# Can I access a AWS Fargate task id from inside a docker container?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am running a PHP app in a Docker container and I would like to include the task id in the stream id used in the logs I send to AWS Cloudwatch. How can I access that?

From my logs I can see that some errors include system context with promising stuff like `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4`, which includes the task id, but this has to be parsed, so was hoping for a cleaner approach like `ENV[SOME_ENV_VAR]` that could be referenced in config files.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a request to the URI at `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4` and parse the response. There isn't another way to access that data from inside the container.